# Google Calendar and Symfony

Tags: php, api, symfony, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar API v3 on a web site with PHP/Symfony2. I've got some troubles to setup the Google API library with Symfony. I fixed PHP fatal errors but there are too many, and some exceptions are generated, like this one :

```
Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
```

Are there some tutorials to integrate Google Calendar in a Symfony project ?
Otherwise, is there a symfony bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no bundle for GoogleCalender integration in Symfony2.

While several provide access to maps and anlytics the [CalendarBundle](http://knpbundles.com/robzienert/CalendarBundle) is no more actively maintained... but might help as a starting point.

You can use [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) or [zendframework/zendgdata](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendgdata) to communicate with the api.

A good entry point / list of methods can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php#836) ( google-api-php ) and a [here](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData/tree/master/library/ZendGData/Calendar) ( ZendGData\Calendar ).

google-api-php-client is still actively maintained while zendgdata is [not](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData).